# Calling Methods on Fragment Creation

Tags: java, android

I have the follow code implemented to utilise fragments for swipe views:

```
public class FragmentMain extends Fragment {
    public FragmentMain() {
    }

    public static FragmentMain newInstance() {
        FragmentMain fragment = new FragmentMain();
        return fragment;
    }

    public TextView STRScore;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
        loadSavedPreferences();
    }
```

I am trying to load some SharedPreferences as a method when the fragment is created. How can I call the method without running into an NPE?

EDIT: my method is

```
    public void loadSavedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        String name = sharedPreferences.getString("storedSTRScore", "12");
        STRScore.setText(name);
```

Comment: I don't see anything related to SharedPreferences to the snipper you shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the `SharedPreferences` in one of the life cycle methods that has the `Activity` context ready since you need a Context to get the preferences. So anything after `onAttach()` should work. You can even put it in your `onCreateView` method.

`SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

or if you want default preferences

`SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());`

Comment: How would I go about putting it after my onCreateView method? I receive the method is unreachable error as its below the return statement.

Comment: Simply call your `loadSavedPreferences();` method before your return statement.

Comment: @Michael Zhang Looking at your new code you will first have to assign your `STRScore` variable by looking it up in your `onCreateView` method by using `STRScore = rootView.findViewById(R.id.STRScore)`. Replace R.id.STRScore with whatever it really is in your fragment_main layout file.

Comment: Ah, I needed to use `rootView.findViewById` instead of `getActivity().findViewById`. Thanks!